# Replace a line of a file with a blank line in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I have a text file called catalog where each line has a name, a surname, a city and a phone number like this:

```
John McJohn Detroit 0301234568
Donald Duck Lake_City 1234567890
Deez Nutz Oxford 2305985531
```

and I want to write a script that will take a keyword as a parameter and will replace its line with the keyword with a blank line.

here's where i got so far:

```
t1=$(grep $2 catalog)      #$2 is the keyword
echo the lines with that keyword are:
echo $t1

t2=$(echo)                       #a blank line

t3=$(tr '$t1' '$t2' < catalog)  #replacing each line with the keyword with a space

echo The lines have been deleted  #not really, they have been replaced with a space

cat catalog
```

This doesn't change the file at all.

I've tried numerous expressions of sed, without any luck (I run the scripts on an old xubuntu version, so I don't know if the sed is supposed to work on this).

I've tried to replace the "t2=$(echo)" thing with '\n' but if fails miserably.

How can this be made?
Is replacing each line with a pattern to a blank line possible at all?

(possible and "works-fine" answer:

```
t1=$(grep $2 catalog)     
echo the lines with that keyword are:
echo $t1
sed "./*$t1.*/s///" catalog
sed "./*$t1.*/s///" catalog > catalogtemp
mv catalogtemp catalog
```

)

Comment: @pvg ive replaced the t3=$(tr ...) with t3=$(sed "s/$t1/$t2/g"). It didn't work

Comment: A single invocation of sed can do this, you don't need anything else. One of the answers linked is identical to your problem, use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ t1="Donald";
$ sed "s/.*$t1.*//" file
John McJohn Detroit 0301234568

Deez Nutz Oxford 2305985531
```

To edit the file *in place*, use the `-i` fag:

```
sed -i "s/.*$t1.*//" file
```

**Edit:**

A more secured syntax to avoid unwanted parameter expansion:

```
sed 's/.*'"$t1"'.*//' file
```

Comment: Is the $kw equal to the $t1 I've written above?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer.

Comment: I've changed the code a bit with your help as followed: t3=$(sed "/,*$2.*/s///" catalog) and then I moved the results of the t3 to the "catalog" as followed: echo $t3 > catalogtemp; mv catalog2 catalog. Now the newlines are gone. All of the text is on the first line. What is wrong?

Comment: `tr` is just for translating or deleting single characters. Don't use it with a pattern. sed should suffice.

Comment: I just got it working, you are right. Thank you. I'm going to update the question with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -v key="${the_key}" '$0 ~ key{$0=""}1' file
```

I'm passing the shell variable `${the_key}` as an argument to `awk`. `awk` matches the whole line (`$0`) against the key and sets the whole line to an empty string if it matches. The `1` at the end will always evaluate to `true` and makes `awk` print all lines of input, modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a oneliner:

```
sed -i "s/^.*<keyword>.*$//" <filename>
```

So if your file is named catalog and your keyword is Donald the script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Should be [[ "$1" == "" ]], leaving the previous
# version for comments to be valid
if [ "x$1" == "x" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
sed -i "s/^.*${1}.*$//" calatog
```

and you would call the script as

```
./<script_name> Donald
```

Comment: I can't really get the if statement. What does the "x$1" == "x" do?

Comment: With bash use: `[[ "$1" == "" ]]`

Comment: @Coursal - it's a check if the script was given a parameter. The "x" is just a precaution so that $1 is not interpreted as an option if it starts with a "-". If $1 would be "-d" the test would try to check if == is a directory.

Comment: @Cyrus you're right, thanks :)